# Submit form with Javascript then handle with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

Not sure how I did this last time or else I wouldnt asking here but here is what I'm trying to do.

I have the usual basic form with a javascript function that will submit the form. Question is that after the form is submitted, I have an if statement in PHP that echos a that the form has been submitted. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
//PHP
if($_POST['submitDelete']){

echo "welcome, You form has been submitted";

}    

//HTML
<form id="form_id" action="" method="POST">
First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br><br>
<input type="hidden" name="submitDelete" TYPE="submit">
</form>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>

//JAVASCRIPT
<script>
function myFunction() {
 document.getElementById("form_id").submit();
}
</script>
```

I can't seem to trigger the if statement in PHP. I also tried using the form name in the if statement and that didnt work either.

Comment: If the HTML and PHP are separate pages, your PHP is never called.

Comment: You need to set the `form action` to the URL of the `.php` file.

Comment: Not separate pages since the action =  "".

Comment: @Carlitos That's not how forms work. Without setting the `action`, the data goes nowhere. You can set the action to the URL of the current page, but you must set the `action`.

Comment: i couldve sworn when the action is left to blank that means it will submit to self.

Comment: @Carlitos No, that's not how it works.

Comment: Additionally, if all you want the button to do is submit the form, then remove the JavaScript completely and either place the button inside the `form` element or use the `form` attribute on the button and set it to the `id` of the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **[`form` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form)** must be told where to submit its data to when the `submit` event takes place. This is accomplished by setting the `action` attribute value for the form. Leaving that attribute empty does not implicitly set the form to post back to the current page. So, if you want to have a single page form/form processor, you need the `action` to be set to the current page file name:

```
<form action="currentPageFileName.php" method="post">
```

Next, there's no reason a single page can't have multiple forms on it. In that case you would need multiple `submit` buttons, each tied to a specific form. For this reason, you can't just drop a `submit` button anywhere on the page that you like unless you add the **[`form` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button)** to the button to tie it back to the form it is supposed to trigger the submit for. Also, if you simply place the `submit` button within the `form` element it "belongs" to, you don't have to worry about this.

Also, you have some invalid HTML with:

```
<input type="hidden" name="submitDelete" TYPE="submit">
```

An element may not have the same attribute repeated within it (the case that you type the attribute in makes no difference since HTML is not case-sensitive). So, that code would wind up simply creating a submit button.

Lastly, if all you want to do with your `submit` button is cause its related form to be submitted, there is no need for JavaScript at all. That is what `submit` buttons do by default.

So, in the end, you can get rid of the JavaScript in your code completely and change your HTML to this:

```
<form id="form_id" action="currentFileName.php" method="POST">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br><br>
  <input type="hidden" name="submitDelete" value="true">
</form>

<button type="submit" form="form_id">Submit</button>
```

Comment: So the button can go anywhere really just need to target the "form=". How about the if statement, how do I target that?

Comment: @Carlitos Yes, if the `submit` button is located outside of its associated form and you link it back to the form's `id` with the `form` attribute, you are good.The PHP code will run as soon as the page is requested. As long as you embed it properly into the page (using the PHP delimiters), it will run. The first time the page is accessed however, the form won't have submitted its data yet, so `submitDelete` won't be true and the `echo` won't happen. After a submit, `submitDelete` will be true and the `echo` will happen.

Comment: Alright thanks for the clarification but back to action = "". I added the action="" blank again and its submitting fine. I do this a lot actually.

Comment: @Carlitos That's not how it is designed to work. You may be finding that it works in your browser, but that's no guarantee it will work in all browsers. You must follow the specification. Please see the link I included in my answer on `form element` and read the section on the `action` attribute. You will notice it does not indicate any default.

Comment: @Carlitos [Here](https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20100624/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#attributes-for-form-submission) is the W3C Spec. on form actions.

Comment: Ok I will keep it mind when working on other projects where users are submitting forms. But since this form is just for me Ill leave it as is. Thanks for being so informative.